# How can I use jQuery's serialize() for croatian characters?

Tags: jquery, ajax, character-encoding

I am using jQuery's `.serialize()` function to send data using `.ajax()`. I have some croatian characters such as čćžšđ and they are not being sent properly. How can I encode them so that they are properly received server side?

Comment: btw my. databese have proper database character set

Comment: How do you know they are not being sent properly?  What is the output of `.serialize`?

Comment: I have alerted (javascript) that data which I am sendig in it look fine, so i think that ajax is making me problems :(

Comment: What about when you go to the ajax URL directly in the browser and print it out?

Comment: Data stays coded ( for example %C48D%) and that is what gets saved in my database

Comment: At what point does it get encoded?  Have you tried decoding it?

Comment: What's your application and database encoding? Is your application file in ISO?

Comment: I send this via jquery ajax : var txt = "contactname=test&contactmail=test&robotest=&contactmessage=ž";, on server side i use $_POST['contactmessage'], then i insert it in database...and ther is no lettter ž just ?? (two quetstionmarks) :(

Comment: UTF-8 without BOM , all files, database characther set latin2 -- ISO 8859-2 Central European, Collation latin2_croatian_ci. Yes I have tried to decode it with php urldecode();

Comment: Sorry guys, my problem was not releted to jquery or ajax...on my server side I added mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);  - configured my mysql connection. Now everything is ok.